# Angular 2: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'

Tags: angular, typescript, sockets, typescript-typings

After having installed the module `socket.io`

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

I have the following error:

*error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'*

**import**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
var map = {
    'socket.io-client': 'node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js'
}

var packages = {
    'socket.io-client': { main: 'socket.io', format: 'cjs', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^1.4.8"
}
```

**typings.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../socket.io-client/socket.io.js" />

declare module 'socket.io-client' {
  var e: any;
  export = e;
}
```

socket.io-client (Directory)
  
- socket.io.js
  
- typings.d.ts

Angular 2 RC5

Comment: I ran `npm install socket.io --save` and in my file: `//@ts-ignore` (to ignore the **visual only** error - had to do the same for express tbh) and `import io from 'socket.io';`. Works perfect.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Update 2021

@nullromo pointed out, the socket.io-client package now has typings built-in. Installing the types separately is no longer necessary

#### Update 2018

To properly use socket.io in the browser you need to install both the socket.io client package and its typings:

```
npm i socket.io-client @types/socket.io-client
```

---

#### outdated:

You are missing typings.
Open `typings.d.ts` and add

```
declare module 'socket.io-client' {
  var e: any;
  export = e;
}
```

You can also try to install typings for socket.io via `npm i @types/socket.io-client`. I don't know if there are typings available, though.

Comment: I don't have `typings.d.ts` file even if i use `npm i @types/socket.io-client`

Comment: Just create one and put `/// <reference path="..." />` into the ts file that imports socket.io. Put the relative path to the d.ts file in there.

Comment: You got me wrong. You'll need to put the `/// <reference path="../path/to/typings.d.ts" />` into the .ts file above `import * as io from 'socket.io-client';`

Comment: sorry - 
npm i @types/socket.io-client
didn't solve it

Comment: Typings have been added to the `socket-io.client` package, so installing the `@types` package is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure to install the correct package with type definitions for socket.io:

```
npm install @types/socket.io-client --save
```

This will include the types in the correct folder and means you would need no further action in any other file since angular will pick this up.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding  this at the top of my app.components.ts

```
  /// <reference path="../../typings/globals/socket.io-client/index.d.ts" />
```