# Angular Socket-io module not found

Tags: angular, sockets

I have an old Angular project I am trying to get running, but it fails everytime with the following error upon serving the app:

```
ERROR in /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/conversational-website/src/app/app.module.ts (8,30): Cannot find module 'ng-socket-io/socket-io.module'.

ERROR in /Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/conversational-website/src/app/app.module.ts (9,30): Cannot find module 'ng-socket-io/socketIoConfig'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ng-socket-io/socket-io.module' in '/Users/sam/lifeai/therealdeal/conversational-website/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 14:0-63
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

In my app.module I am importing it like so:

```
import {SocketIoModule} from 'ng-socket-io/socket-io.module';
import {SocketIoConfig} from 'ng-socket-io/socketIoConfig';
const config: SocketIoConfig = {url: 'https://api.CENSOR.com:3000/', options: {secure: true}};
...
imports: [
  SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
]
```

And finally, this is how I'm importing it from the component:

```
import {Socket} from 'ng-socket-io';
```

Referencing this: [Angular 2: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226729/angular-2-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-socket-io-client), I cannot seem to even find a typings file. How do I proceed?

Comment: Did you `npm install` your dependencies?

Comment: @MikeTung yes, and I have also tried installing it manually with the -g flag.